# drools fusion CEP: How to get Properly entryPoint on 7.20. kieSession.getEntryPoint("My Entry Point") returns NULL

Tags: drools, entry-point, drools-fusion

When initializing Drools and kiesession everything works perfectly.

`kieSession.insert(Event) [this is a CEP app]` works nicely, but I can not initialize EntryPoint.

`EntryPoint ep = kieSession.getEntryPoint("My EntryPoint")` returns NULL always.

Is it  necessary to initialize the entry point in somehow? What I concluded is that my kiSession does not have an EntryPoint called "MyEntryPoint" and the getEntryPoint() does not create it, so it always returns NULL.

```java
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
            // Load KieContainer from resources on classpath (i.e. kmodule.xml and rules).
            KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieBaseConfiguration config = kieServices.newKieBaseConfiguration();
            config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);

            // Initializing KieSession.
            LOGGER.info("Creating KieSession.");
            kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
            kieSession.addEventListener(new DebugEventListener());

            // Collection<KiePackage> x = kieSession.getKieBase().getKiePackages();
            DroolsActionHandler drlActionHandler = new DroolsActionHandler();
            // kieSession.insert(drlActionHandler);
            kieSession.setGlobal("drlActionHandler", drlActionHandler);

            samplingStream = kieSession.getEntryPoint("StufaSampingStream");
```

```xml
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" equalsBehavior="equality" eventProcessingMode="stream" default="true" packages="resources.rules.actuators">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules" default="true" type="stateful" clockType="pseudo">
<!--            <fileLogger file="/var/log/sintechs/drools" threaded="true" interval="10"/> -->
        </ksession>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

samplingStream always returns `Null`.

Comment: "I think it was mentioned somewhere in documentation (at least I read it), that all entry points are being initialized by rules." said by Ivan Kostyuk on (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox/FMfcgxwCggCQWgvGkNNcrLjWxfmCQwXr)

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your rules file is correct. Sometimes, there can be small mistakes like package name in rule file does not match the one mentioned in kmodule.xml. You can also include kie Maven plugin in your pom.xml. Any small mistake in your drl file, might fetch entry point as null. I had the same issue. The package name in drl file was different than what was mentioned in kmodule.xml. After fixing, entry point was not Null

Comment: That's the point, greate. I've got a good reply in google-groups also. The entrypoint is initialized only if any rule has mention to that entryPoint, else, there is no initialization on it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/drools-usage/Q5jbeYFqD0g/3ORDCFlUAwAJ